# How do I delete observations with no data in Stata?

Tags: stata, data-cleaning

I have data with IDs which may or may not have all values present. I want to delete ONLY the observations with no data in them; if there are observations with even one value, I want to retain them. Eg, if my data set is:

```
ID val1 val2 val3 val4
1 23 . 24 75
2 . . . .
3 45 45 70 9
```

I want to drop only ID 2 as it is the only one with no data -- just an ID.

I have tried Statalist and Google but couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: A simple way is to use `drop if missing(val1-val4)`

Comment: Sorry Aspen. My example could have been clearer -- the variable names are not linear.

Comment: `missing()` returns 1 if ANY of the arguments evaluates to missing.

Comment: @Dimitriy You're right. I gave it a quick test and jumped the gun on this one. `missing()` also does not accept the varlist syntax such as val1-val4.

Answer (score 7):

This will *also* work with strings as long as they are empty:

```
ds id*, not
egen num_nonmiss = rownonmiss(`r(varlist)'), strok
drop if num_nonmiss == 0
```

This gets a list of variables that are not the id and drops any observations that only have the id.

Comment: Thanks Dimitriy, but the critical variables are numeric.

Comment: `dropmiss` (SJ) is dedicated to this problem. Your search strategy should start with `search` in Stata, not the internet.

Comment: `dropmiss` is definitely the way to go. One can re/discover it easily with `findit drop observations with missing data`.

Comment: See also UPDATE to my answer on `missings` (SSC).

Answer (score 4):

Brian Albert Monroe is quite correct that anyone using `dropmiss` (SJ) needs to install it first. As there is interest in varying ways of solving this problem, I will add another.

```
 foreach v of var val* { 
     qui count if missing(`v') 
     if r(N) == _N local todrop `todrop' `v' 
 }
 if "`todrop'" != "" drop `todrop'
```

Although it should be a comment under Brian's answer, I will add here a comment here as (a) this format is more suited for showing code (b) the comment follows from my code above. I agree that `unab` is a useful command and have often commended it in public. Here, however, it is unnecessary as Brian's loops could easily start something like

```
 foreach v of var * {
```

UPDATE September 2015: See http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1308777-missings-now-available-from-ssc-new-program-for-managing-missings for information on `missings`, considered by the author of both to be an improvement on `dropmiss`. The syntax to `drop` observations if and only if all values are missing is `missings dropobs`.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to do it which helps you discover how flexible local macros are without installing anything extra to Stata. I rarely see code using locals storing commands or logical conditions, though it is often very useful.

```
    // Loop through all variables to build a useful local
    foreach vname of varlist _all {    

            // We don't want to include ID in our drop condition, so don't execute the remaining code if our loop is currently on ID
            if "`vname'" == "ID" continue  

            // This local stores all the variable names except 'ID' and a logical condition that checks if it is missing
            local dropper "`dropper' `vname' ==. &"     
    }

    // Let's see all the observations which have missing data for all variables except for ID
    // The '1==1' bit is a condition to deal with the last '&' in the `dropper' local, it is of course true.

    list if `dropper' 1==1

    // Now let's drop those variables
    drop if `dropper' 1==1

    // Now check they're all gone
    list if `dropper' 1==1

    // They are.
```

Now `dropmiss` may be convenient once you've downloaded and installed it, but if you are writing a do file to be used by someone else, unless they also have `dropmiss` installed, your code won't work on their machine.

With this approach, if you remove the lines of comments and the two unnecessary list commands, this is a fairly sparse 5 lines of code which will run with Stata out of the box.

Comment: "local variables" in your text should read "local macros". Stata's (12) limit on characters for a macro is: 8,681 (small), 165,200 (IC), and 1,081,511 (MP/SE). Thats enough to hold quite a few variable names. `help limits` is the reference here. In your example, `r(varlist)` _really_ holds all variable names. You just need to run ``display "`r(varlist)'"`` (note the quotes).

Comment: As a side note: if you want to refer to all variables in the dataset, you can use `_all`. For example, `foreach vname of varlist _all { ... `. No need for `unab` here.

Comment: Your code assumes numeric variables. `missing()` is the way to a more general test.

Comment: I think it is still important to note that the point I made initially was that local macros can store logical conditions. In many datasets where the dataset is derived from surveys, missing data is often recoded as a -9 or -99, also a response of "I don't know" may be recorded as a -33. It is often appropriate to drop these data for certain analyses, in which case `missing()` is inadequate. The code I display can be easily modified for this purpose.

Comment: Also, I am quite new to these forums, and haven't quite learned the etiquette when something I've posted is incorrect. I've tested `ds` and it is certainly correct that `"`rvarlist'"` contains all variables of the pattern. Should I edit and delete that part of my post? Other than `unab` being unnecessary I think the logic of the solution is very valid as well as demonstrating the usefulness of macros that is applicable this and other scenarios.

Comment: It's certainly good practice to correct mistakes by editing. The code I wrote can also be modified to cope with other conventions on what indicates missing, but one Stata recommendation is to use `mvdecode` in such cases.